# What is the difference between _form_validate vs form_validate?

Tags: forms, nodes

I'm unsure which one you should use for a form_validation.

Seeing that `_form_validate()` starts with a `_` makes it a private function following the Drupal coding standards if I'm not mistaken.

So my guess is that a form validation should be done with `hook_validate()`.

But the question remains: what's the difference between the two and where should they be used?

---

EDIT:
I misunderstood the `hook_validate()` which is not the `_validate` "hook" used in the form API. I'll leave the question unchanged so other users can learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're totally correct, Drupal's coding standards denote anything with a `_` prefix is seen as a pseudo-'private' function. As such the `_form_validate()` function was never meant to be called directly. Unless you really need to use it, and you're absolutely positive there's no other way to accomplish what you want, I wouldn't advise using it.

In fact only one function in the whole core system calls `_form_validate()`: [`drupal_validate_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7). It would stand to reason that you should be using *this* function instead (being that it's not marked as a private function).

These are the functions that Drupal uses internally to validate a managed form, so if you're using the Form API correctly you should never need to call them. Adding validate handlers to a form to validate individual elements is the correct way to do things.

Just to clear up a wee bit of terminology as well, [`hook_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7) has nothing to do with the form API as such; it's used by node-providing modules to validate nodes before saving. The validation handlers that you add to forms (with custom forms, or through `hook_form_alter()`, don't have a particular 'Drupal name' that I'm aware of.

Also, you don't actually even need to use the standard named `_validate` function if you don't want to...you can add a function with any name as a form validate handler:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_strangely_named_function';
```

Drupal just looks for `FORMNAME_validate()` by default, and runs it if it exists.

Comment: I see now, have to implement the form validation in the definition of the form fields.

Comment: Yep :) The [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) has some good information on the subject in general if you're interested, in particular the [Validating Forms](http://drupal.org/node/751826#validating) section

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for! so the `_validate()` in the form API is not the `hook_validate()` but some hidden hook in the form API :)

Comment: No, it's just another one of Drupal's naming conventions; you don't even *need* to use it...you can add a function with any name as a form validate handler (`$form['#validate'][] = 'my_strangely_named_function';`, etc.). Drupal just looks for `FORMNAME_validate()` be default, and runs it if it exists

Comment: @Clive You probbly want to add that last comment to the question body :)

Comment: @Berdir Good point, will do :)

Answer (score 3):

hook_validate performs node validation before a node is created or updated. This hook is invoked only on the module that defines the node's content type.

_form_validate checks if all required fields are filled and if max lengths of text field is not exceeded. If it finds any errors of such kind it fires form_error or form_set_error functions.

You need to use hook_validate when you define a new node's content type in your module and want to do some customized validation for this content type. This hook won't work for non-node forms.

Generally you won't need to call _form_validate, because it is being called automatically during form submission process.

The best practice to validate an arbitrary form is to create a custom validation function.

For example you have a function that defines your form:

```
function YOURFORM_form(){
    // form definition
}
```

The custom validation function for this form would be

```
function YOURFORM_validate(){
    // form validation
}
```

Comment: I never said there was :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's a custom form that you'd like to validate?

If your form function is called `mymodule_form()`, then you should add a function called `mymodule_form_validate($form, &form_state)`. That function will be called automatically, and you'll be able to validate the submitted values using `$form_state['values']`.

If there are errors, you should call `form_set_error()`, which will prevent the submission and notify the user.

`hook_validate()` is only used to validate node submissions, if your module provides a content type, and can't be used to validate any other forms.